# iptables подмена ip

Tags: сервер, https, apache2, iptables, openwrt

1) Есть устройство, которое умеет стучаться **только** на определенный домен.

2) Есть сервер поддержки, к которому привязан тот самый домен.

3) Есть отладочный сервер поддержки, который соответственно к домену не привязан.

4) Оба сервера работают по  https

*Задача/идея:*

Прописать на роутере с openwrt *iptables* так, чтобы весь трафик, предназначенный для домена перенаправлялся бы на отладочный сервер.

Для отладочного сервера с IP 192.168.2.100 и IP, к которому привязан домен 2.2.2.2 пишу так:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 2.2.2.2 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.100

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.100 -j SNAT --to-source  2.2.2.2
```

Почти работает, а именно: **Пинги** успешно перенаправляются.

Проблема почему то возникает только с https трафиком. Пакеты запроса соединения доходят на сервера, он даже пытается на них отвечать, но до того, кто их запросил они уже не доходят.

При этом если обратиться к домену с указанного тестового сервера, то все запросы и ответы проходят.

Думаю, что проблема во второй строке, что то в ней не так :)

Прошу особо хорошо знающих iptables помочь.

Comment: А с другим TCP-трафиком проблемы возникают? Скажем, с HTTP или SSH? Работают ли пинги с тестового сервера до клиента?

Comment: Вообще кажется, что будет более "прямо" подменить адрес в DNS (если на устройстве можно прописать произвольный DNS-сервер, то это вообще получается довольно красиво), а не устраивать MitM с IP-адресами.

Comment: @yeputons С DNS лень было связываться. Разобрался таки с iptables ( решение ниже)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение.

Необходимо обязательно прописать на интерфейс локальной сети вот так:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br-lan -j MASQUERADE
```